# Is there a way to access the form validation on ion-input if using HTML pattern?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic6

I am trying to validate an ion-input using the regex pattern directly on the HTML object to only allow numbers from 0 to 24. This works perfectly fine, the form is getting red if a wrong number/text, etc. is entered.

```
<ion-input [pattern]="numberPattern" #hoursInput></ion-input>
```

As I am generating those inputs in a *ngFor loop, is there a way I can somehow access the valid state of all ion inputs together so I can disable a button if one of them is invalid?

```
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let project of (projectList$ | async)>
            <ion-label>{{ name }}</ion-label>
            <ion-input ...... [pattern]="numberPattern" #hoursInput></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

And my button is in the footer and should be disabled if the inputs are invalid :)

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add following to HTML:

```
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="disableMe"></ion-input>

  <ion-button [disabled]="disableMe <0 || disableMe >24 || !disableMe">Im the button</ion-button>
```